# Timeshift weekly cron emails

Tags: cron, anacron, timeshift

I recently installed timeshift and set it to backup weekly.  However, when I looked in /etc/cron.d, I only found timeshift-hourly which ran:

```
0 * * * * root timeshift --check --scripted
```

which appears to check with timeshift if a backup is schedule and if so, do it.

However, I would like to set a cron email for every time I backup and I'm guessing that if I set if for timeshift-hourly, then I will get an email every time that it checks every hour.  How would I be able to set a cron email for every time that timeshift does a backup and not every time it checks to see if it's time to backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already built-in to Timeshift, just disabled by default. The following picture is from the Timeshift setting menu; just uncheck the *Stop cron emails* box and you should be good to go.

[image: Timeshift Settings]

Comment: Where would I add my destination email address?

Comment: Since the Timeshift process is run as root, that's who would get the email. You could create an alias for root, but that would shift all of root's emails.

Comment: I just edited crontab with `vim /etc/crontab` and added `MAILTO=myaddress@domain.com`.  Hopefully, this works.

Comment: I've never tried that switch, but it should work.